# How to prevent pandas accessor to issue override warning?

Tags: python, pandas, accessor

I have written an accessor to pandas dataframes, very similar to the example in https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.api.extensions.register_dataframe_accessor.html.

```py
@pd.api.extensions.register_dataframe_accessor("geo")
class GeoAccessor:
    def __init__(self, pandas_obj):
        self._obj = pandas_obj

    @property
    def center(self):
        # return the geographic center point of this DataFrame
        lat = self._obj.latitude
        lon = self._obj.longitude
        return (float(lon.mean()), float(lat.mean()))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ds = pd.DataFrame({"longitude": np.linspace(0, 10),
                   "latitude": np.linspace(0, 20)})
    print(ds.geo.center)
```

However, when I call the code the second time, I get a warning message

```
untitled3.py:12: UserWarning: registration of accessor <class '__main__.GeoAccessor'> under name 'geo' for type <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'> is overriding a preexisting attribute with the same name.
  class GeoAccessor:
```

I have tried adding the following line to the top:

```py
import warnings

warnings.filterwarnings(
    "ignore", message="registration of accessor <class '__main__.GeoAccessor'>")
```

but that only works when everything is in one file. As soon as store the file in "testlib.py" and do an "import testlib" somewhere else, I get the same warning again.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delete the accessor inside a try/except block before creating it. It's probably not very clean but it works for me:

```
try:
    #delete the accessor to avoid warning 
    del pd.DataFrame.geo
except AttributeError:
    pass

@pd.api.extensions.register_dataframe_accessor("geo")
class GeoAccessor:
    ...
```

I tried to do the same with an xarray but it doesn't work because xarray accessors are read-only. I get this error:

> AttributeError: 'DataArray' object attribute 'myaccessor' is read-only